# Exception while attempting to add an entry to the access log

Tags: logging, tomcat7

Tomcat 7 can't write the access log and throws the following exception.

```
Nov 17, 2016 5:10:37 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter log
WARNING: Exception while attempting to add an entry to the access log
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.log(CoyoteAdapter.java:555)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:182)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Tomcat which is fixed in Tomcat 8.0.29. Upgrading Tomcat should resolve this problem.
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58578

Other way is to modify access logging pattern not to include cookie. Use something like this:

```
pattern="%t %H request:%{SESSIONID}r %m %U %s %q %r"
```

instead of

```
pattern="%t %H cookie:%{SESSIONID}c request:%{SESSIONID}r %m %U %s %q %r"
```

in server.xml.

```
    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
```